# Public stored procedure to access sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to make available some part of sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats view to all users in my SQL Server. The goal is to provide that information without breaching SQL Server security.

I'm not an DB expert, but I have prepared this code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[LastTableUpdate]   
    @Table nvarchar(50)   
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER 
AS   
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(database_id) as 'Database', 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) As TableName, 
    max(last_user_update) as user_update,
    max(last_system_update) as system_update
 FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats WHERe database_ID=DB_ID() AND object_id=OBJECT_ID(@Table)
 GROUP BY database_id, object_id
```

Next I grant privileges

```
GRANT EXEC ON dbo.[LastTableUpdate] TO PUBLIC
```

But when I'm calling it got

```
Msg 15562, Level 16, State 1, Procedure LastTableUpdate, Line 5
The module being executed is not trusted. Either the owner of the database of the module needs to be granted authenticate permission, or the module needs to be digitally signed.
```

Can you assist me, how should I proceed? As I have mentioned - my goal is to keep DB as secure as possible.

Comment: why seeing DMV results is a security issue ?

Comment: I would like to avoid to give user VIEW SERVER STATE privileges

Answer (score 10):

Module signing (unlike hustlin') is easy. Essentially, you:

1. Create a certificate
2. Create a login based on that certificate
3. Grant permissions to that login
4. Sign the stored procedure
5. Profit

---

```
use master;
go
create login [foobar] with password = 'f00bar!23';
go
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.[LastTableUpdate]   
    @Table nvarchar(50)   
AS   
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(database_id) as 'Database', 
    OBJECT_NAME(object_id) As TableName, 
    max(last_user_update) as user_update,
    max(last_system_update) as system_update
 FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats WHERe database_ID=DB_ID() AND object_id=OBJECT_ID(@Table)
 GROUP BY database_id, object_id
 go
 grant execute on dbo.LastTableUpdate to public
 go
EXEC sp_ms_marksystemobject 'LastTableUpdate'
go
 create certificate [CodeSigningCertificate]
    encryption by password = 'Sooper$ecretp@ssword123'
    with expiry_date = '2099-01-01',
    subject = 'Code Signing Cert'
go
create login [CodeSigningLogin] from certificate [CodeSigningCertificate]
grant view server state to [CodeSigningLogin];
go
-- nothing up my sleeve
execute as login = 'foobar';
exec dbo.LastTableUpdate 'n'
revert

-- doesn't work - login [foobar] doesn't have permissions
go
-- here's the magic
add signature to dbo.[LastTableUpdate]
    by certificate [CodeSigningCertificate]
    with password = 'Sooper$ecretp@ssword123';
go

execute as login = 'foobar';
exec dbo.LastTableUpdate 'n'
revert

-- works now!
```

---

Note: I took out the `EXECUTE AS OWNER` clause from your procedure; you don't need it now that the caller will get `VIEW SERVER STATE` permissions for the context of this stored procedure run only.

Answer (score 1):

You're sure your db has trustworthy enabled?
Try this query if it is the case:

```
USE master
GO
ALTER DATABASE [db] SET TRUSTWORTHY ON
GO
```

Comment: MS recommends against this though? "We recommend that you leave the TRUSTWORTHY database property set to OFF to mitigate certain threats that can exist as a result of attaching a database that contains one of the following objects:" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/trustworthy-database-property?view=sql-server-ver16